# xtext - how to set code areas, with excluded grammar check

Tags: xtext

**Summary:** I wish to set left and right margin for my own language -  areas of code in which grammar check is excluded.

**Background:** Using xtext,  I am trying to create nice Cobol editor. So far I finished grammar and encountered problem with margins and comments.

Left margin I can include within grammar: after ‘\n’ up to 6  !‘\n’ chars.

That is not solving my problem though. SLComment starts with '*' being placed at 7th position from left. I would be able to catch that with ‘\n’ '*' -> ‘\n’  rule, once I somehow exclude first 6 chars in each line.

I can’t just leave it as ‘*’ -> ‘\n’ and delegate position check to validate , because its messing up multiply rule, which of course uses ‘*’. Placing comment rule just after grammar margin rule isn’t also a solve, since that way I can’t catch margin within the first line of the code.

Also I know that I won’t solve right margin problem(exclude area after 78 position for example) using grammar rules.

I guess there is a way to interfere in text that xtext is checking, but haven’t found solution or hint how to accomplish this.

Also tried to find out if this can be made through preprocessing somehow, but also failed to find any hint how to do so.

Or maybe It is possible to use two grammars at once. Extra one will get each line and hide margins?

Hope I were able to describe what problem I’m facing and what I tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use something like a LINE_START_COMMENT terminal rule that captures the first 6 characters of every line, and then hide it accross the grammar.

```
terminal LINE_START_COMMENT: 
    // Up to 6 chars that are NOT a new line
    '\n' (!'\n')? (!'\n')? (!'\n')? (!'\n')? (!'\n')? (!'\n')?
;
```

Then, using this approach I guess you should also modify your full line comment rule, to something like:

```
terminal FULL_LINE_COMMENT: 
    LINE_START_COMMENT '*' 
    (LINE_START_COMMENT '*' | !(LINE_START_COMMENT) )+
    (LINE_START_COMMENT)?
;
```

Here I have defined the FULL_LINE_COMMENT to end after the following LINE_START_COMMENT. To check for several consecutive commented lines, you have to accept as a comment anything thats not the comment terminator (in this case the LINE_START_COMMENT) or the LINE_START_COMMENT with a new '*' after it.